# Remove overlay with position

Tags: android, overlay

I want to remove same overlay at the specific position. This is my code for add the overlay, but how can get the position for every overlay?

```
public void visual_overlay(List<DatiOverlay> list_overlay){
    CustomOverlay itemized_overlays = null;
    GeoPoint point = null;
    for(int ov=0;ov<list_overlay.size();ov++){
        itemized_overlays = new CustomOverlay(drawable,mappa, Integer.toString(list_overlay.get(ov).get_id_segnalazione()),list_overlay.get(ov).get_via(),list_overlay.get(ov).get_citta(),list_overlay.get(ov).get_descrizione(),list_overlay.get(ov).get_cek_feed());
        point = new GeoPoint((int)(list_overlay.get(ov).get_lat() * 1E6), (int)(list_overlay.get(ov).get_lng() * 1E6));
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, list_overlay.get(ov).get_nome(), list_overlay.get(ov).get_prezzo());
        itemized_overlays.addOverlay(overlayItem);
        mappa.invalidate();
        mappa.getOverlays().add(itemized_overlays);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You remove an overlay from a MapView like this:

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
if (mapOverlay != null) mapOverlays.remove(someOverlay);
```

Comment: but what is someOverlay ? I want to remove all except mylocation overlay. The code up take only overlay (not my location) how can save only position of that ? Thanks

Comment: someOverlay is a reference to the overlay you want to remove. You need to keep references to overlays you may wish to remove later, either by references to the overlay object, or its int id. So for example when you create all the overlays, store them so you can then remove them.